# Does the solution set of y"-5y'+6y=0 form vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does the set of all solutions of the following differential equation form a vector space ?

$$y"-5y'+6y=0 $$

After solving it, l get

$$y(x)=ae^{2x} +be^{3x}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I think it should be a vector space and $0$ is a solution if $a=-b$ but I am still a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to solve the equations in order to check if they form a vector space. Just note that if $f,g$ are two such solutions and $\lambda,\mu$ two scalars, then

$$(\lambda f+\mu g)''-5(\lambda f+\mu g)'+6(\lambda f+\mu g)=\lambda (f''-5f'+6f)+\mu (g''-5g'+6g)=0,$$

so $\lambda f+\mu g$ is still a solution, and since the zero function check the equation you can conclude that this is a subspace of the space of twice differntiable functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your general solution for the differential equation is correct.

But we have : $0$ is a solution $\iff a=b=0.$

Let $y_1(x)=a_1e^{2x}+b_1e^{3x}$ and $y_2(x)=a_2e^{2x}+b_2e^{3x}$ and $ \alpha \in \mathbb R.$

Then it is easy to see that $y_1+y_2$ and $ \alpha y_1$ are also solutions of the differential equation .

Hence the solutions of the differential equation form a real vector space.